# Evento Mysql para deletar linhas com data expiradas

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar um evento para deletar linhas, que a coluna `date` esteja com a data expirada, ou seja menor do que a atual.

Estava tentando com o seguinte comando:

```
create event e on schedule every 1 day do delete from Reserve where date < curdate();
```

Mas depois fui testa-lo adicionando uma linha com ma data já passada e trocando o `every 1 day` para `every 1 second` Mas não tive sucesso...

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a query correta para o meu problema?

Comment: Tente where trunc(date) < curdate(). Ou ainda, veja se o formato do teu campo date está igual a saida do curdate.

Comment: Se você tentar algum outro evento ou um diferente parâmetro para o where, ele executa?

Comment: Não consegui, @Diego. E sim, o formato utilizado é o mesmo.

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho Tentei com outros parâmetros, mas não tive sucesso também...

Comment: é bom usar CronJob para coisas como essas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `dbName`.`eventName`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY // or 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'Description'
DO
    BEGIN

    DELETE FROM `dbName`.`TableName` WHERE `DateCol` < NOW();

    END
```

Amigão adapte esse código acima! (como você não disponibilizou os campos eu não posso adaptar para vossa pessoa :/ )

LEMBRANDO É NECESSÁRIO ATIVAR O `MySQL Event Scheduler`

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181458/auto-delete-a-record-in-table-when-date-is-expired

Comment: Não sabia que tinha que ativar algo antes :(. Mas deu tudo certo aqui, Raphael. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas, boa sorte no seu projeto, qualquer duvida estou aqui para ajudar, e se quiser conceder a recompensa eu fico feliz :D, mas mesmo assim, boa sorte.

Comment: Sim, concederei. Mas só posso daqui a 23 horas. :))